# How do we use uri endpoint mapping in spring integration

Tags: web-services, spring-integration

I am trying to configure spring integration using annotation. Instead of payloadqnameendpoint mapping I would like to use URI endpoint mapping. I found many examples with default URI endpoint but I required an annotation example without default end point.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look to the [`AnnotationActionEndpointMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e1421) support in the Spring WS! As you see it is based on the division between POJO methods and annotations on the them. The **POJO** is a main word there. This kind of framework magic allow us to separate low-level protocol from end-application business logic. From other side Spring Integration's `AbstractWebServiceInboundGateway` implements `MessageEndpoint` meaning that the whole SOAP hard work will be done in this implementation. It isn't a POJO. 
Of course this topic is a different story, but you should understand from here that `MessageEndpoint` and `MethodEndpoint` work a bit different. At least they do messaging logic from different levels of SOAP request.

So, we really can't map `<int-ws:inbound-gateway>` with `@Action` or similar just because it is a whole SOAP endpoint already.

From other side, having `AnnotationActionEndpointMapping` from Java config, you can fully get rid of `<int-ws:inbound-gateway>` and configure your `Endpoint` to delegate desired `@Action` to the methods of `@MessagingGateway`. And it will work beucase the hard SOAP work has been done already by Spring WS framework.

I don't know you that this code will work, but you can check or let me know and I'll test it and come back to again:

```
@Endpoint
@MessagingGateway
public interface OrderEndpoint {

    @Action("http://samples/RequestOrder")
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "getOrderChannel")
    Order getOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest);

    @Action("http://samples/CreateOrder")
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "createOrderChannel")
    void order(Order order);

}
```